# Lose Youtube player when it scrolls out of view because of reusable cells in table view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swift4, ytplayerview

I am building a instagram like news feed. Each post is either a spotify streaming song or a Youtube video playing in its own YTplayer view. If I play a video cell and then scroll through the feed, the video keeps playing even though you cant see it. At this point, if I scroll to a spotify post and hit play, I want the video to stop playing. I am not able to do this. I tried to keep track of the 'last played' video cell and stop the YTplayer instance, but the cell is reused by that point and doesn't exist. So I can't do it that way. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can do this?

My Custom tableview cell class has the YTplayer view, I only load some of the cells with youtube video ID's, which become the Youtube video cells when the table view is loaded.

Comment: i am facing same problem may you please describe your solution

Comment: Hi @AbecedarioPoint, I just marked my answer and included more details, let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Right after my dequeueReusableCell I check if the cell contains a video post. I use a string flag I set in the post to do this. If it does, I declare my tableview controller as its playback delegate. From there on, if I play that cell and scroll to a spotify cell and play that one, I use player.stopVideo() to stop the Youtube player.

Comment: When the user taps on a Youtube cell I basically declare my TableViewController as its playback delegate. Declare a YTPlayerView variable. Declare the controller as the delegate in the viewDidLoad. Now you have a youtube playerview that you can stop/start at any point from the main controller. When the user taps on the youtube cell I just make the controller YTPlayerview = Cell's YTPlayerView.     `var youtubeplayer: YTPlayerView?` .   In viewDidLoad:  `self.youtubeplayer?.delegate = self`    When the user taps on the cell:  `youtubeplayer = tappedCell.playerView`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
           didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell,
           forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   // access the playing video of the cell and stop it 

}
```

Comment: This will stop playing the video the moment the cell scrolls out of view right? That's what I am interpreting the documentation to mean. I don't want that to happen. I want the video to keep playing even if it's out of view and only stop if another post is played.